# Angular 2 CORS using mail service(mialgun)

Tags: angular, cors, mailgun

I am using mailgun api to send mails from my test app. Whenever I am trying to send mail it gives me:

```
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Funny thing is that when I enable CORS plugin in chrome it works fine, and mail are sent. What is wrong? i thought that CORS must be setted on server side ? So why chrome is blocking my request?

use of code:

```
var requestHeaders = new Headers();
requestHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.mailgunApiKey);
requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.request(new Request({
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    url: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/' + this.mailgunUrl + '/messages',
    body: 'from=' + this.sourcePageMail + '&to=' + recipient + '&subject=' + subject + '&text=' + message,
    headers: requestHeaders
  }))
  .subscribe(success => {
    console.log('SUCCESS -> ' + JSON.stringify(success));
  }, error => {
    console.log('ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the request header

```
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

and the OPTIONS

```
OPTIONS /resources/post-here/ HTTP/1.1
Host: bar.other
```

Comment: I added requestHeaders.append('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');  but i dont understand part with Options. I am begginer with that